# Display Edit and Delete buttons in list view in Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

In Backpack for Laravel version 3.4, the Edit and Delete buttons have been moved into a modal. I now have to click a plus sign to display the Edit and Delete buttons.

I'm wondering if there is a configuration option for reverting to the old behavior or if I have to manually edit the view files to get this behavior back.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - that’s due to the responsive behaviour - Backpack automatically hides columns that won’t fit the screen, starting from the right. You can disable this new default behaviour with $this->crud->disableResponsiveTable();

But I recommend you show fewer columns if they don’t fit on a regular desktop, or use the “length” attribute on the columns to limit how wide the columns are.

Hope it helps!